# Не работает проверка времени, в тг боте, как правильно реализовать?

Tags: python, aiogram, бот

```
@dp.message_handler(state=TaskForm.waiting_for_text)
async def process_text(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # сохраняем текст задачи в состояние
    data = await state.get_data()
    task = {'weekday': data['weekday'], 'time': data['time'], 'text': message.text}
    print(f"Создана новая задача: {task}")
    tasks.append(task)
    await state.finish()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,f"Ваша задча: {task['weekday']},{task['time']}, {task['text']}")
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Задача успешно создана")
    
    now = datetime.now()
    weekday = now.strftime("%A")
    h_and_m = now.strftime('%H:%M')
    print(h_and_m)
    today_ru = days_dict[weekday]
    print(task['time'])
    if today_ru == task['weekday'] and h_and_m == task['time']:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Напоминаем, что сегодня в {task["time"]} ты хотел {task["text"]}')
```

В этом кусочке бот должен проверить правильность времени, с днем недели от отлично справляется, а вот с часами и минутами нет, я не могу понять в чем проблема, тип данных у обоих переменных одинаковый.